# execute a function after html table is been populated

Tags: jquery

I want to call a function which will add a class to all anchor tags inside a table.

The problem is the table is being populated dynamically.
So i dont know when to call or on which event to call my fucntion to add class to anchor tags.

I tried following.

```
 $('document').ready(function () {
        $('#htmlTable a').addClass("needsclick");
    });
```

Kindly advise

Comment: How you are populating table?? Show us.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [DataTable plug-in for JQuery](https://www.datatables.net/) then you can write your code into `draw` event of `dataTable` like follows:

```
$('#htmlTable').on( 'draw.dt', function () {
    $('#htmlTable a').addClass("needsclick");
} );
```